# Google voided Corporate Contributor License Agreements

Tags: open-source-definition

So when I tried to signed the CLA for my company, it failed and Google told me that "Please have an authorized executive sign this document. ..."

To me it's not quite clear their definition of authorized executive. How do I get autorized if I am the only employee or I am the boss. By default, Google use Docusign for digital signature and I just signed the default signature (which is generated by Docusign automatically)

So here's my question:

1. How do you signed it? It would be really great if someone has experience on this.
2. There is a required field "title" which is unclear to me. What kind of information should I fill in this field. ( I filled in "Mr")

https://cla.developers.google.com/clas/new?domain=DOMAIN_GOOGLE&kind=KIND_CORPORATE

Comment: "Title" here likely means "Job title within the organization". I think Google is expecting something like "CEO" or "Business owner" or similar, indicative of a position that has the authority to broadly assert that "each employee of the Corporation designated by You is authorized to submit Contributions on behalf of the Corporation.".

Answer (score 3):

As a generic (late) answer: Google (and lots of companies) expect contracts signed by **the person legally authorised to represent the company**. If you are the only one then your best title is "*owner* of the company" or whatever your legal environment provides (here around I am the "CEO" even if it's a one-man show).

In Europe at least Google usually asked for company registry papers which specifically contained the persons who were authorised to represent the company, then the signature sheet which connected these persons to signatures, then they have checked the signatures and names on the contract. It really went smoothly, provided you have all the required papers.

But if you live in a country with less than full paper trail it might be a challenge to prove you're authorised. "I am the owner and the sole executive" usually works well.